# How can I format a code block in Jira without the Markdown plugin?

Tags: jira

Jira (hosted version) does not seem to support Markdown without a plugin. How can I paste and format a code block in a Jira issue comment or description?

Comment: Definitely a correct answer was given

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [Atlassian JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) `{code}` macro is covered in section [Advanced Formatting](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=advanced) within the [Text Formatting Notation Help](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all):

> Makes a preformatted block of code with syntax highlighting. All the optional parameters of {panel} macro are valid for {code} too. The default language is **Java** but you can specify others too, including **ActionScript, Ada, AppleScript, bash, C, C#, C++, CSS, Erlang, Go, Groovy, Haskell, HTML, JavaScript, JSON, Lua, Nyan, Objc, Perl, PHP, Python, R, Ruby, Scala, SQL, Swift, VisualBasic, XML** and **YAML**.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> {code:title=Bar.java|borderStyle=solid}
> // Some comments here
> public String getFoo()
> {
>     return foo;
> }
> {code}
>
> {code:xml}
>     <test>
>       <another tag="attribute"/>
>     </test>
> {code}
> ```

Comment: The problem with this documentation is that it doesn't tell you how to specify something other than Java (say SQL, for example).

Comment: {code:<language>} such as {code:sql} for sql

Comment: The Advanced Formatting section has been updated to include all possible language types:
The default language is Java but you can specify others too, including ActionScript, Ada, AppleScript, bash, C, C#, C++, CSS, Erlang, Go, Groovy, Haskell, HTML, JavaScript, JSON, Lua, Nyan, Objc, Perl, PHP, Python, R, Ruby, Scala, SQL, Swift, VisualBasic, XML and YAML.

Comment: They document “Java” → `java`, but “Plain Text” → what? `plain text`, `plaintext`, `plain-text`, etc.?

Comment: Just use `{code:none}` if you don't want any syntax highlight (or `{noformat}`)

Answer (score 2):

By default it uses the **Default Text Renderer** on the `Description` field. You may need to edit your field configuration(s) (as admin) to use the **Wiki Style Renderer**